# Missing IF em procedure

Tags: mysql, if, stored-procedures

Fiz a seguinte procedure, mas no `END//` aparece `'missing if'`, alguém sabe o porque?

O William me ajudou com esse problema, porém sempre que tento cadastrar, a procedure só vai para o ultimo `else`.

Chamei dessa forma:

```
call prc_cadastrar_usuario(18823123132, 'Jorgin', 'Alho', 'jorginalho', 'alho', @a);


DELIMITER //
drop procedure if exists prc_cadastrar_usuario //
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_cadastrar_usuario (
in n_cpf varchar(11),
in n_nome nvarchar(30),
in n_sobrenome nvarchar(30),
in n_usuario nvarchar(30),
in n_senha nvarchar(255),
out msg nvarchar(200)
)
BEGIN
declare v_cpf varchar(11);
declare v_nome nvarchar(30);
declare v_sobrenome nvarchar(30);
declare v_usuario nvarchar(30);
declare v_senha nvarchar(255);

-- seleciona  no banco os dados que entraram
set v_cpf := (select cpf from tbl_usuario where cpf = n_cpf);
set v_usuario := (select usuario from tbl_login where usuario = n_usuario);

-- verifica se os dados da select são iguais aos que entraram
if ( (v_cpf <> n_cpf) && (v_usuario <> n_usuario) ) then
    insert into tbl_usuario (cpf, nome, sobrenome) values (n_cpf, n_nome, n_sobrenome);
    insert into tbl_login (usuario, senha, cpf_login_fk) values (n_usuario, n_senha, n_cpf);
    set msg := 'Cadastrado!'; 
elseif ( (v_cpf = n_cpf) && (v_usuario <> n_usuario) ) then
    set msg := 'CPF já cadastrado!'; 
elseif ( (v_cpf <> n_cpf) && (v_usuario = n_usuario) ) then 
    set msg := 'Usuário já cadastrado!'; 
else 
    set msg := 'Erro ao cadastrar';
end if;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

tabelas:

```
create table if not exists tbl_usuario(
    cpf varchar(11) not null,
    constraint cpf_pk primary key(cpf),
    nome nvarchar(30),
    sobrenome nvarchar(30)
    );

create table if not exists tbl_login(
    id_login int not null auto_increment,
    constraint id_login_pk primary key(id_login),
    usuario nvarchar(30),
    senha nvarchar(255),
    cpf_login_fk varchar(11) not null unique,
    constraint cpf_usuario_login_fk foreign key (cpf_login_fk) references tbl_usuario on delete cascade on update cascade
    );
```

Comment: ELSEIF ao invés de ELSE IF : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html

Comment: Porque Null comparado com alguma coisa é sempre Null. Digamos que o CPF nao esteja cadastrado, nesse caso a Query select cpf from tbl_usuario where cpf = n_cpf retorna Null e quando voce compara v_cpf <> n_cpf é false mas v_cpf = n_cpf é falso tambem, entao cai para o else. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: Como eu poderia resolver isso?

Comment: Sugiro voce alterar o Titulo para que reflita sua dúvida atual, uma vez que o problema do END IF foi resolvido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque NULL comparado com alguma coisa é sempre NULL. [Referência](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Digamos que o CPF não esteja cadastrado, nesse caso a Query "select cpf from tbl_usuario where cpf = n_cpf" retorna NULL e quando você compara v_cpf <> n_cpf é NULL (nem false nem true) e v_cpf = n_cpf é NULL também, então cai para o else.

Aqui uma solução:

```
set v_cpf := (select cpf from tbl_usuario where cpf = n_cpf);
set v_usuario := (select usuario from tbl_login where usuario = n_usuario);

if ( (v_cpf is null ) && (v_usuario is null) ) then
   /*insere novo registro*/
elseif ( (v_cpf is not null ) && (v_usuario is null) ) then
    /*'CPF já cadastrado!*/
elseif ( (v_cpf is null ) && (v_usuario is not null) ) then
    /*'Usuario já cadastrado!*/
else
    /* Usuario e CPF já cadastrados!*/
end if;
```